# NuxtJS + Express + Docker: URIError on Requests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, express, nuxt.js

I get the error "URIError: URI malformed" when I try to log in using @nuxtjs/auth-next. But only if the Nuxt App is running in a Docker Container. If I start it with "yarn dev" or "yarn start" its working fine and the request succeeds.

Chromes console shows me that the request finishes after the URIError when the app is running in the Docker container:

`XHR finished loading: POST "http://example:3000/api/auth/login"`

But the response body of this request is just some HTML from Nuxt and not the JSON I expect from the express backend.

I am using the @nuxtjs/auth-next module for the login which is calling the '$auth.loginWith()' from an axios store.

nuxt.config.js

```
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

export default {
  target: 'static',
  srcDir: './',
  head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s - Dein digitaler Restauranthelfer',
    title: 'digimenu',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'de'
    },
    meta: [
      {charset: 'utf-8'},
      {name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'},
      {hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: ''},
      {name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no'}
    ],
    link: [
      {rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico'}
    ]
  },
  css: [],
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/vuex'
  ],
  components: true,
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify'
  ],
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
/*    '@nuxtjs/proxy'*/
  ],
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      dark: true,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: colors.orange.darken4,
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3
        }
      }
    }
  },
  server: {
    host: process.env.HOST,
    port: 3000
  },
  serverMiddleware: [
    {path: '/api', handler: '~/api'},
    {path: '/api', handler: '~/middleware/session.js'}
  ],
  axios: {
    proxy: false
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    axios: {
      baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
      browserBaseURL: process.env.BROWSER_BASE_URL
    }
  },
  privateRuntimeConfig: {
    axios: {
      baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
      browserBaseURL: process.env.BROWSER_BASE_URL
    }
  },
/*  
proxy: {
    '/api/': { target: process.env.BASE_URL, pathRewrite: {'^/api/': ''}}
  },
*/
  router: {
    middleware: ['auth']
  },
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        scheme: 'local',
        token: {
          property: 'token',
          global: true
        },
        user: {
          property: 'user'
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/api/auth/login', method: 'post'},
          logout: { url: '/api/auth/logout', method: 'post'},
          user: {url:  '/api/auth/user', method: 'get'}
        }
      }
    },
    redirect: {
      login: '/login',
      logout: '/',
      home: '/admin'
    }
  },
  build: {
    transpile: [
      'defu'
    ]
  }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  nodeserver:
    image: node:14-alpine
    working_dir: /app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command: [ "yarn", "start" ]
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${DB_USER:-digimenu}
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD:-digimenu}
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

.env

```
# 'nodeserver' if I run it with docker and 'localhost' if I run it with 'yarn dev'
HOST=nodeserver
BASE_URL=http://nodeserver:3000
BROWSER_BASE_URL=http://nodeserver:3000
```

Please help me fix this, can't count the number of hours trying to solve this anymore

I tried:

- With and without proxy (nuxt.config.js)
- rebuild docker container
- build image with the app to create container from (instead of using volumes and the node:14 image)
- tried to change the HOST, BASE_URL, and BROWSER_BASE_URL (127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0, localhost, nodeserver)

But the error still appears.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

Ofc after posting here I found the solution. Changing following in the nuxt.config:

```
{
  ssr: true,
  target: 'server'
}
```